# Unnacesible SD CARD after making gold card

Tags: partitioning, mount, sd-card, filesystem-corruption, raw

I made gold card by [this guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1248095) from my Samsung EVO plus SDHC. I formatted my card to FAT32. Then I inserted it into my Android Phone and through [GoldCard Helper](https://apkpure.com/goldcard-helper/name.starnberger.guenther.android.goldcard) I got mmc2 reversed CID (SD Card Serial). Then, I downloaded my own gold card image (iso) by [this](https://huygens.hoxnet.com/goldcard.html) website. Next, I launched HxD hex editor. I replaced/rewrote lines 00000000-00000170 (I think it is MBR, see this [thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24824/what-is-a-goldcard-and-how-does-it-work?answertab=active#tab-top)) on my SD card by all data in gold card image (iso).

Unfortunatelly, I probably made a mistake and the card is not working anymore on any OS. When I open **diskmgmt.msc**, it says "*no media*". **Diskpart** says same. [Bootice](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bootice_64_bit.html) says "*ReadFile error*". ReadFile error". [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) says "Read error" when running Quick Scan Analyse and can't found any partition. [Minitool Partition Wizard Free](https://www.partitionwizard.com/) says "*bad disk*" and show 2048 GB capacity (SD Card has 32 GB).
Linux can't mount it. `dmesg` throw

> error mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising sd card.

Android phone can't recognize the card too.
My adapter is working fine when I insert other SD card.

I don't need data recovery, but I want access the card and use it. Is there a hope?

Thank you for help :).

Comment: Nope. But fortunately EVO cards have a ten-year warranty.

Comment: Rather than "this guide" you should describe what you actually did *here*. We prefer not to rely on external links as their contents may change or be removed. What did you actually do? Where did it fail? What happened? What is a "gold card"? Chances are though that the card is simply dead.

Comment: Ok. I added details. I also searched about my problem and I think that SD card has corrupt MBR. Do you think it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm *guessing* you have a badly mangled file system. The *good* news is you can't break it any more than you have. Any tool you use needs to *ignore* the filesystem you are using. Windows is a bit naff about stuff like that.

The SD card error smells like a red herring (yay!). Annoyingly it seems to be an [obscure bug](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2071864.html)

Assuming its the filesystem, and you want to play it safe, consider trying to use DD to image the drive, just to see if it *actually* reads. dd dosen't care about the filesystem.

I'd try zeroing out the drive - dd or [shred](https://linux.die.net/man/1/shred) run on the *device* does the job. I've also found in a few situations, the official [SD association SD card formatting  tool](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/)  might do the trick

If all else fails. contact Samsung and get it swapped under warranty as Ignacio's mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for response. But Linux (Ubuntu) can't recognize my SD card. I can't see it with commands like lsblk or fdisk -l (there isn't any /dev/mmcblk0). Dmesg return "mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card. Cannot verify signal voltage switch. lspci return for my SD card reader "Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a). So, neither dd nor shred works :(

Comment: ehh. mmcblk was for embedded ones no? Coulda sworn the last time I trashed a card it was sdX

Comment: I assume that USB card readers are mounted as /dev/sd* and PCI card readers are mounted to /dev/mmcblk*. But I don't know it certainly.

Comment: From the error in dmesg, it would be mmc.... however it's utterly screwed.